# Access external URL(Google.com) from PhoneGap(Android)

Tags: android, cordova

I am new to PhoneGap and Android.I am unable to access Extrenal URL' like google from PhoneGap,i tried Iframe and Window.Location.Href but not sure why it's not working.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
<title>PhoneGap</title>
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8" src="phonegap-0.9.3.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.css" /> 
<script src="jquery-1.4.3.min.js"></script> 
<script src="jquery.mobile-1.0a1.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>
<iframe src="http://www.google.com"></iframe> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 11):

Have you added the external URLs to the whitelist? There is a file in `/res/xml` in your project called `PhoneGap.xml`

Here is an example of one of my `PhoneGap.xml` files:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phonegap>
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
    <access origin="http://devgeeks.org"/>
    <access origin="http://*.phonegap.com"/>
    <log level="DEBUG"/>
</phonegap>
```

Comment: this is added but how to call from java script ....
navigator.app.loadUrl('http://google.com'); is NOT working

Answer (score 6):

Opening an external link in phonegap / android is only possible two ways:
Source: https://build.phonegap.com/blog/access-tags

check blogpost of phonegap. They're explaining what the android default is, and what you can do about it.

Follow the discussing on the phonegap forum: 
http://community.phonegap.com/nitobi/topics/make_links_use_external_broswer_consistently

Edit:

1. Add the following code to your config.xml.

   ```
    <access origin="http://www.domain.com" browserOnly="true" />
   ```
2. Add:

   ```
    function loadURL(url){ 
       navigator.app.loadUrl(url, { openExternal:true }); 
    }
   ```
3. Add:

   ```
    <a onclick="loadURL('http://www.domain.com')" href="#">Url</a>
   ```

Answer (score 1):

The access xml helped me. You can use the `navigator.app.loadUrl` function to get the url loaded in the current webview - look in the `cordova.js` file for details of the options