# PhoneGap on Android wont load external scripts

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I'm making a simple app that will load a google map. but the problem is everytime I load this

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
```

It wont run on my android emulator while on desktop it works fine. how can I let Phonegap or Android allow external scripts to work/load?

UPDATE: I always get this error "Application Error: The connection to the server was unsuccessful.(file///android_asset/www/index.html). But if I removed the google map script. it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, the whitelist is the issue like @TDeBailleul said, but he was referring to the location of the whitelist in iOS not Android.

In android, it is in /res/xml/PhoneGap.xml

There is an example of this file in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9187479/878602

Comment: It's still not working. I haven't tried it on an actual phone though. This is my only problem on PhoneGap right now.

Comment: Maybe some more of what you are trying to do? I certainly get no errors including that script tag in a vanilla app

Comment: Can you please give me a sample of your phonegap.xml? here is mine but does not work.                                             `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<phonegap>
    <access origin="http://127.0.0.1*"/>
    <access origin="http://maps.googleapis.com*"/>
 <access origin="http://maps.google.com*"/>
    <log level="DEBUG"/>
</phonegap>`

Comment: Can I know what version of PhoneGap are you using with the vanilla app you made?

Comment: Well, I would try just putting "http://*" as an access origin to determine if that is the problem. The google maps scripts call lots of other scripts on other domains (http://maps.gstatic.com for instance) so it would be best to just rule it out.   Also I am using 1.4.1

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot. looks like there is something wrong with my emulator. I just managed to get an android phone and tested it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

In the lastest PhoneGap version(2.7.0). You should modify the file "*config.xml*" located in */res/* directory of your Android project. Simply add:

```
<access origin="http://www.yourdomain.com" subdomains="true" />
```

Domains are assumed blocked unless set otherwise.

Answer (score 0):

In the phonegap version 5.1 things are different than the above answers.

There is a plugin installed called `cordova-plugin-whitelist`. Read the file at `plugins/cordova-plugin-whitelist/README.md` to know details.

There are multiple kind of whitelist(navigation, intent and access-origin) and in this case you need the content-security -policy.

```
<!-- Enable all requests, inline styles, and eval() -->
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="script-src: 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval' 'https://maps.google.com'">
```